# Workflow not working on SharePoint 2016 workflow task list

Tags: 2016

we have a scenario in which we have to trigger a workflow when a task is created in workflow task list.

but it is not starting workflow when task is created, however, it works fine, when manually triggered or when task is updated manually.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like SharePoint is preventing a circular reference.  If the task list that the workflow creates tasks in is the same task list that you want to initiate the workflow on item creation, you are creating a circular reference.  If you create a task and the workflow starts, it creates a task that starts another workflow, etc.

I recommend you separate the task list that triggers the workflow and the task list that holds the workflow tasks into 2 separate lists.

Comment: I agree with your point of circular reference, but is their any way to stop sharepoint to prevent circular ref? because the workflow which we intend to use does not create any further task.

Comment: or can we use remote event receiver to trigger the workflow when an item is created?

Comment: If it is not creating a task, then there is no harm is creating a new task list to associate the workflow to.